# ASP.NET MVC site takes too much time to load probably because of a Windows service running on the same server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, dll, windows-services

I have a dedicated Windows 2008 server with several websites and 1 windows service running.

The service runs every 30 seconds and is pretty CPU intensive. However all sites are loaded really fast except for the one that is closely connected with the service. This website project dll is referenced from the service, and I think this is the reason it is so slow.

Has anyone had any experience with this? How can I improve the loading time of the site?

**Update**

Here's more information:

Only the first time load is slow. Subsequent loads are fast. The website and the service access the same MongoDB database. The service also references the website's dll and uses a lot of classes including UsersRepository.

Stopping the service makes the application run normal.

Comment: Have you tried stopping the service and seeing if that resolves the slowness. That will at least isolate the issue.

Comment: Not enough information.  How does the service interact with the site?  Does the service cause blocking of the site? (Does it lock records the site needs to load?) In general, the first time your run a site it takes longer to load.  Does it load fast on subsequent loads?  Does each page take a long time?  I could keep asking questions for hours.

Comment: Dustin, yes I have. It does resolve slowness. @Mystere Man, you're right, I've provided not enough info, I tried to answer your questions in the original question.

Comment: Set lower CPU priority for the windows service.

Comment: If it's only the first load, it's probably just building your site. With IIS8 you could have your site "warmed up" so there's no first load.

Comment: @Esteban Araya, all other sites are built in less than 1 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was the service's fault. I solved the problem by making a clone of the bin folder which is used for the service only.